# Can't use Migration Assistant. Need an update?

Tags: macos, software-update, migration

I have had issues with my macbook pro due.  My fault.  I backed it up, and decided to do a fresh copy of the MacOS.
I had so many issues with that.  Recovery didn't work.  It froze.  Repeatedly.  Did Internet Recovery, and that didn't work either.  Also froze.  Found my disc and got that to install.  Couldn't download anything from the app store.  Finally figured out to click the top left apple icon and do software update.  Then app store worked.  Installed the latest iOS I had in the purchased page - OS X El Capitan.  Got all the updates done and caught up and it is running pretty great.  Except - I can't get the High Sierra to install.  That freezes.  I've left it all day and tried several times.  Never gets half way.

When I run Migration assistant, it tells me I can't use my hard drive because it has a more recent version of iOS on it.
The OS on my laptop is currently 10.11.6, and it is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011), and I don't know how to check what is on the hard drive.  And I can't seem to update the laptop anymore.

Can anyone help?  Is there a way to migrate all my stuff manually?? ugh

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question: "iOS" refers to the operating system on iPhones and iPads. "macOS" refers to the Operating System on iMacs, MacBooks, and MacPros. In order to help you we need to be clear about what *exactly* you are referring to.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you added the specific model of MacBook Pro you have, i.e., MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) as copied from my work computer's "About this Mac" Overview tab. 
Also be more specific with the version numbers of the Operating Systems you attempted to install at each point in your explanation.